# Knockout click binding with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to add an click event to my button that will send the Id, Category and Name as parameters only when the button is clicked.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: tehTab()">
    <tr>
       <td data-bind="text: $data.Category"></td>
       <td data-bind="text: $data.Name"></td>
       <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn chart_btn" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-html="true" data-placement="right" container="body" tabindex="0" data-original-title="" title="" style="border:none; background-color:white" data-bind="attr: { id: $data.Id,'data-contentwrapper':'.chartdraw' + $data.Id},click: getLast7($data.Id, $data.Category, $data.Name) , text:$data.Value"></button>
         <div data-bind="css: 'chartdraw' + $data.Id" class="chartdrawetc" style="display:none">ASD</div>
       </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

even if I try to change:

```
click: getLast7($data.Id, $data.Category, $data.Name)
```

with

```
 attr: { id: $data.Id ,onclick: getLast7($data.Id, $data.Category, $data.Name)
```

it still fires the **getLast7** method as many times as the tehTab length.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Adding `()` after function name will call it.  You will have to use `.bind`

```
click: getLast7.bind(this, $data.Id, $data.Category, $data.Name)
```

#### Sample

```js
function vm(){
  this.notify = function(str){
    console.log(str)
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="click: notify.bind(this, 'Hello')">Click me</div>
```

Comment: You are right! It seems that I only needed to add .bind to make it work. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

Even though you can fix it with a `bind` in your click binding, I don't think this is the best solution.

The `click` binding passes the clicked model to the listener *by default*. Bind will create a new function for each item and moves logic to your views.

Here's an example:

```js
var data = [
  { Id: 0, Category: "A", Name: "A0" },
  { Id: 1, Category: "B", Name: "B1" },
  { Id: 2, Category: "C", Name: "C2" },
  { Id: 3, Category: "D", Name: "D3" }
];

ko.applyBindings({
  data: data,
  log: function(item) {
    console.log(item);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: data">
  <li data-bind="click: $parent.log, text: Name"></li>
</ul>
```

Create an extra `onClick` function if you need to extract properties to an argument list:

```js
var data = [
  { Id: 0, Category: "A", Name: "A0" },
  { Id: 1, Category: "B", Name: "B1" },
  { Id: 2, Category: "C", Name: "C2" },
  { Id: 3, Category: "D", Name: "D3" }
];

var log = function(id, cat, name) {
   console.log("Item ", id, "was clicked. (name:", name, "category:", cat); 
}

ko.applyBindings({
  data: data,
  onClick: function(item) {
    log(item.Id, item.Category, item.Name);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: data">
  <li data-bind="click: $parent.onClick, text: Name"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Good if you just need the current context, but not if you want to call the function with other data like a parent context. Example: `data-bind="click: $root.dataClicked.bind(this, $data, $parent)"`

Comment: Certainly true, thanks for commenting. I do believe though that you should strive to prevent dependencies to/from binding context. Whenever I can, I define the relation between parent/child models by passing references in code rather than through views.

Answer (score 0):

For click binding inside a loop, use **this** to get values of entry in current row.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: DataList">
 <tr>
  <td><input type="label" data-bind="text: Id"></td>
  <td><input type="label" data-bind="text: Category"></td>
  <td><input type="label" data-bind="text: Name"></td>
  <td><input type="button" data-bind="click: $parent.getCompleteDetails" value="View Details"/></td>   
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

In Knockout script, get current row entries using this keyword

```
  self.DataList   =ko.observableArray([]); //this is used to populate the data entries.
  self.getCompleteDetails= function() {   
    alert(this.Id);
    alert(this.Category);
    alert(this.Name);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use that and works fine.

html:

```
<input type="button" value="click to test" data-bind="click: $root.getCompleteDetails" />
```

javascript:

```
getCompleteDetails: function (item, event) {
            // you can access all properties in item parameter 
        }
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply wrap the click handler (getLast7 in your case) in a function. You can then supply it any parameter you'd like. Properties from $data, custom values or even properties from different contexts:

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  container: {
    containerId: 42,
    items: [{
      id: 1,
      category: 'item category',
      name: 'item name',
      log: function(id, category, name, custom, containerId) {
        console.log(`id: ${id}, category: ${category}, name: ${name}, custom text: ${custom} containerId: ${containerId}`);
      }
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="with: container">
  <div data-bind="foreach: items">
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: function() { log($data.id, $data.category, $data.name, 'custom text', $parent.containerId); }">Click me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain your original binding syntax, have the function in your viewmodel return a function.

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  Id: 15,
  Value: ko.observable('Click Me!'),
  Category: 'standard category',
  getLast7: function(id, category, name){
    return function() {
      console.log("You clicked and passed in " + id + ", " + category + ", " + name);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<button data-bind="click: getLast7($data.Id, $data.Category, 'Hello World!'), text:$data.Value">
```